# Swift Regex with variable (not fixed) String subcomponent

Tags: swift, regex

Is it possible to create a reuseable Swift 5.8+ `Regex` pattern with a variable (not-fixed) component? If yes, how?

Conceptually, consider the use case where a keyword variable is to be used as part of the regex. This would be an analog to interpolations in the `String` type.

```swift
func example(keyword: String) {
    // non-functional concept shorthand
    var regex = /…\(keyword)…/
    // do something with regex 
}
```

It's likely that a `/…/` regex literal does not have a syntax which supports this approach. And, there may be issues with similarity of the `\(…)` `String` interpolation syntax the regex `(…)` capture syntax.

*Rather, can any of the several newer (non-`NSRegularExpression`) regex definition approaches be used in some way to support a variable `String` sub-component?*

Comment: It appears this isn't possible. Not supporting string interpolation was explicitly mentioned as a motivation factor behind the `/.../` syntax over the existing `"..."`: "It wouldn't be compatible with other string literal features such as interpolations." [SE-0354 Regex Literals](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0354-regex-literals.md#reusing-string-literal-syntax)

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for providing a source doc link which provides design consideration which ruled out string features in regex literials. This info pruned the solution search space to `RegexBuilder` for the newer Swift regex implementation.

Comment: Regex builder isn’t newer, both it and regex literals use the same implementation. One is just more more portable, while the other is more expressive

Comment: @Alexander Understood. The "newer" meant the group of regex features is regex literals & `RegexBuilder` (macOS 13+, …) relative to the "older" `NSRegularExpression` (macOS10.7+, …).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

RegexBuilder provides a convenient way to build this. For example:

```swift
import RegexBuilder

let string = "prefixandthissuffix"

func example(keyword: String) {
    // non-functional concept shorthand
    var regex = Regex {
        "prefix"
        keyword
        "suffix"
    }

    if let match = string.wholeMatch(of: regex) {
        print(match.output)
    } else {
        print("\(keyword): nomatch")
    }
}

example(keyword: "andthis")  // prints match
example(keyword: "andthat")  // nomatch
```

Note that the `Regex` needs to be rebuild each time the keyword string needs to change. The dynamic rebuilding can be encapsulated in a function.

```swift
func quotedRegex(keyword: String) -> Regex<Substring> {
    let regex = Regex {
        /"/
        keyword
        /"/
    }
    return regex
}

let string = "{\"key1\":\"value\"}"
for word in ["key1", "KEY1", "key2"] {
    var regex = quotedRegex(keyword: word)
    regex = regex.ignoresCase() // transformed
    if let match = string.firstMatch(of: regex) {
        print("\(word) matched \(match.output)")
    } else {
        print("\(word) not matched")
    }
}

// print:
//   key1 matched "key1"
//   KEY1 matched "key1"
//   key2 not matched
```

Comment: I added some detail to your answer to note that the current `Regex` does not have a mutable `String` subcomponent which can be dynamically changed. Thus, the `Regex` needs to be rebuilt for each string component change. That said, this answer does provide a useful solution to the stated problem.